# Return the matching word in an efficient manner

Tags: java, arrays, string, pattern-matching

Given array of strings like `[“crane", "drain", "refrain”]` and a pattern such as `*an*` where * can match any number of characters.

Return the matching word in an efficient manner. *(In this example, `"crane"`)*

I can solve it in very simple way:

```
    String [] array = {"crane", "drain", "refrain"};
    String pattern="an";

    for(String s:array){
        if(s.contains(pattern)){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to optimize the code performance in java? Consider array can contains a large number of strings.

Comment: As phflack notices, if your list of words is all in one string, you're probably want to wrap your needle in a pattern with word delimiters, or split the string first by whichever conventional separator.

Comment: In your description you use a pattern *an* (with asteriks on both sides) but in your code you only use "an" as pattern. That is only okay in this case. But if you ask for other patterns like "a*n" (with asterisk in the middle) that will not work.

Comment: What kind of optimizations are you asking for? Speed? Length of Code? Use for all kind of patterns like regex?

Comment: optimizations for speed. @RalfRenz. Question updated

Comment: Where do you return anything? I can't see it. Usually, assignments have to be taken to a reaonable strong degree literally. I guess you cite the assignment literally, is this true?

Comment: My tried solution is just matching the example. The code can be used in method to return it.

Comment: @nagendra547: I would appreciate, if you would find the solution yourself. It has a much better learning effect. My hints aren't meant to insult you. The exercise is to write something, which returns the result, not something which could be used for it. I promise, chances are good, that you are confirmed of your solution, one time you saw it.

Comment: Same here, my replies are also not to insult you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with Regular Expressions (regex).

```
public class RegexExample3{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        String [] array = {"crane", "drain", "refrain"};

        for(String s:array){
            if(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(".*an.*", s))
            System.out.println(""+s);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) if someone doesn't know about regex and would want to understand it.

Comment: So is this more efficient? Do you think 'return something' is 'println'?

Comment: @userunknown Let's appreciate his reply, instead of getting into nitty bitty of code..

Comment: @userunknown While it doesn't match the description, it matches their example.  And in some cases, "return something" is printing it out

Comment: @phflack: So do you think pattern matching against contains(pattern) is much of a difference here? Or what else could be meant by the question, supposed it is cited carefully?

Comment: @Rohan Thanks for your reply. I know about pattern matching, just wondering is there any better solution here! Appreciate your response.

Comment: @userunknown It is certainly more versatile, but for performance one should test both and benchmark

Comment: @Rohan: Interesting, that you suppose to benchmark it, instead of doing it yourself. You seem as if you were pretty sure without doing it, since else, your suggestion doesn't make any sense. According to my - maybe simple - benchmarks, the original solution is of 2 orders of magnitude faster than yours. I can't explain why, but IMHO it is up to you, to indicate, why your solution is superior.

Comment: @userunknown also note that Rohan hasn't said anything about benchmarking

Comment: @phflack: But he should have, because the question is about 'in an efficient manner' and the user asks 'Is there a way to optimize the code performance in java? Consider array can contains a large number of strings.' - Without further hints, this usually means performance by time.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want to check if a word is match a pattern without using any Regex, contains..etc
i suggest to encode the pattern in way that if you encode a word will have same hashing...

but, in your case i suggest to do this:

```
    static String EncodeString(String x){

    String output="";
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){


        // *an* == 0110
        char c=x.charAt(i);
        if(c=='n'|| c=='a'){
            output +="1";
        } else {
        output +="0";
        }
    }
    return output;
}public static void main(String args[])
{

      String pattern="*an*";
    String enPattern=EncodeString(pattern);
      String word="xyanxvsdanfgh";
    String enWord=EncodeString(word);

    System.out.println(enPattern+" "+enWord);


    int v1=Integer.parseInt(enPattern);
    int v2=Integer.parseInt(enWord);
    System.out.println(" % :"+ v2%v1);// notice here if word not match the pattern then the MOD operation will NOT return 0


}
```

Answer (score -2):

The assignment asks for a return of **the** matching word, so the assumptions are, that there is one word, and only one word matching.

And if there is just one word, it is efficient to return early, instead of looping on. You have been close.

```
String matching (String pattern, String [] array) {
   for (String s:array) 
       if (s.contains (pattern)) 
         return s;
    return "";
}
```

Think about alternatives, how to measure s.contains (pattern) against Regex.pattern.matches, how many cases you would have to generate, to find a difference. Without doing the measurement, you're not sure, that it isn't less efficient. Maybe the pattern should be precompiled?

In such assignments, supposed you cited it carefully, you usually have to take everything very carefully.

Often people have good ideas about a topic, and can't hesitate to implement their first idea to it. Don't do it!

> Given array of strings like [“crane", "drain", "refrain”] and a
>   pattern such as *an* where * can match any number of characters.
>
> Return the matching word in an efficient manner. (In this example,
>   "crane")

Be very sensible for every violation of your expectation. It is asked for returning the matching word. Did you notice the singular case? What might it mean in the context of *efficient manner*?

Of course you have to know your teacher, whether he is a bit sloppy or not and fluent in the language, he uses. But interfaces of methods which fit together are a big issue in software development and reading the specs carefully, too. You soon end up investing much time into a solution which works, but doesn't fit the problem.

Returning an empty String is probably not the best idea, but seems sufficient for the level, and without further context it is hard to decide, what an appropriate reaction would be, if nothing is found. Again, the wording suggests, that there is exactly one solution.